# Trying to get the URN of other users LinkedIn Account

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I hope you can help me out. I have a registered app linked in that has the following permission. I am not sure if it's enough because it doesn't say in the Microsoft document what scope I need, but I am trying to retrieve other users' profiles using the LinkedIn API. I have no problem retrieving the current user's information using "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me" but when I am trying to use "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{person ID})" to retrieve other user's information I am getting access denied error. And also, is there a way to get any users ID through the use of their profile URL? I found an article that is possible using the v1 LinkedIn API, but I don't seem to find an article or documentation that can be done in v2 api. Thank you for the help

[image]